# CSS !important not working width child container

Tags: css, width

I am trying to work with markup that someone else has created. My problem is that I have set the width of a parent container for use on other elements, but want to over-ride this on one specific child container that I can target using `.ticket13 .text b` and set it to 400px. However this doesn't work.

If you check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJMQb/) you can see the problem. How can I get `.ticket13 .text b`to be 400px wide without changing the markup?

```
<div class="left-container">
  <div class="ticket13">
    <p class="text">
      <b> I want this container to be 400px wide </b>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

.ticket13 .text b { width: 400px !important; }

p.text {
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
}
P.text {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.3em 0.3em 0;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 0;
  width: auto;
}


.ticket13 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 186px;
}
.ticket13 {
  border: medium none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.left-container {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: You'd have to make the `b` a block level element, by either setting it's `display` to `block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: why do you set the parent `.ticket13` to 186px if you want a child to be 400px? you should rethink your markup layout, also I would target the <p>, rather than the <b>

Comment: Ah yes, that is true.  Or surround the <b> with a span perhaps but you would have to do the same thing to the span as @kalley suggested.

Comment: @koala_dev the markup was created by someone else and they did not do a great job.

Comment: @kalley's idea worked feel free to post that as the answer. Thanks for the comments everyone.

Comment: posted it as an answer already. Feel free to mark it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to make the `b` a block level element, by either setting it's `display` to `block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: In my case to set the width explicitly with !important don't have worked (width was calculated dynamically further based on content length at runtime). To set  display to block was the only solution (without to set the width).

Answer (score 0):

Put the markup for the child BELOW the markup for the parent.  You shouldn't even need to use `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Try use that:
`.ticket13 .text b {
width: 400px !important;
display: inline-block;
}`

Answer (score 0):

To do that you have 2 solutions:

```
.ticket13 .text b {
    width: 400px!important;
    display: block;
}
```

or

```
.ticket13 .text b {
    width: 400px!important;
    float: left;
}
```